# Problem: table sorting and pagination with jquery plugin tablesorter

Tags: jquery, pagination, tablesorter, pager

I have a table which has 100 rows which also has pagination. each page shows up 10 records. I am using jquery plugins tablesorter and pager. Sorting and pagination work like a charm. Now what I am trying to do is to show up a div when i click on each table cell. when i load the 1st page of the table (i.e: 10 records) it works fine. but when I either sort it or go to any other page using the pagination it stops working. the popup does not come up at all. I also just tried with an alert. Even that does not work. I then figured out that if I comment out $(this).trigger("appendCache") popup works all fine. but my table displays all the rows. Pagination goes for a toss. Can someone please help me on this?

Many thanks,
Racky

Comment: This question is way too localized and you didnt even provide any code.  Do you just want a random guess for an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to assign your show-the-div logic using `.live()`, which will attach the behavior to objects that are added dynamically to the page (like new table rows appearing as a result of pagination).

So something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('table#your_table td').live('click', function(){
        // your popup code
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Ken,
    That fixed my problem and saved my many hours. I appreciate your time and super knowledge. This was a preloaded table and the rest of the pages are being hidden(cashed) by the paginator plugin.

@Josh: I would have posted the code if Ken hadn't replied. I will do it next time onwards. Thanks for your response.

Many thanks,
Racky

Comment: You should probably accept his comment if it fixed your problem ;)